# How to change test to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

In a test file I had the functioning line:

```
get edit_password_reset_path(member.reset_token, email: "")
```

and in the controller I had:

```
def edit
end
```

This worked but now I had to change the controller to:

```
  def edit
    if @organization
      render action: "editorg"
    elsif @member
      render action: "editmem"
    end
  end
```

This allows for a different form to show up for a passwords reset, depending on the type of user. So there is an editorg.html.erb and an editmem.html.erb. This again works.

What not works is the old test line. But how should I change it since the route path that the test line refers to has not changed? As it is, it still looks for edit.html.erb and I get the error message: `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template password_resets/edit ...`

In case more information on the test file is needed:

```
  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @member = members(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @member.email }
    assert_not_equal @member.reset_digest, @member.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    member = assigns(:member)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(member.reset_token, email: "")
    ...here I get the error message.
```

The logic in the controller that populates `@organization` or `@member` is below. I show that it looks in two tables to define the user (it will find the user in one of these two tables).

```
before_action :get_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    def get_user
      @member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
      @organization = Organization.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end
```

Comment: This sounds like neither `@org` or `@mem` is set so rails is trying to render the default view `password_resets/edit` because neither of your `render action: ...` statements is executes.

Comment: I guess that's true but on the development server it works fine. It's only in the test that it doesn't work. I think also because `get edit_password_reset_path(member.reset_token, email: "")` directly posts to the path...? And perhaps it also has to do with the need in the test to use `assigns` so that the controller might not recognize it as a "member"...?

Comment: What's the logic in the controller that populates `@org` or `@mem`?

Comment: I added the logic (and now fully written it out as it really is instead of the abbreviations).

Comment: You should REALLY split up your test case. Try to aim for one assertion per test case and never do anything after an assertion. If you bundle all your assertions into one test case its going to be really hard to track failures and you are also hard ordering the tests so that they only will run in the order specified - which will mask test ordering issues (test that only pass if run sequentially)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer to give more space, although it's not a complete solution.

If you look at your test code you're doing:

```
get edit_password_reset_path(member.reset_token, email: "")
```

i.e. making the request without an email address. This is probably what you want in that the password reset request should be made with the reset token. But in your `get_user` you're only performing find by email queries so that won't work.

You probably want to change this to something like

```
if params[:email].present?
  # find by mem/org by email
else
  # try finding by reset token
end
```

You mention this works in development so take a look at the URLs and the parameters that are being passed in development, and take a look at your routes or parameters to see where param contains the reset token so you can use that in your find queries as needed.

**Whatever, you do, be careful you don't end up with a solution where a password can be changed using only an email address and without requiring the correct reset token.**

Comment: Thanks that pointed me to the solution. Adding `else redirect_to root_url` in `def edit` in the passwords reset controller solved it.  

The problem was indeed that no email address was passed, thereby testing the sitution that someone didn’t copy-paste the reset link correctly. `Def edit` did not account for the situation (in contract to update and create) where no organization nor member was found (so I was wrong to say that in this specific situation it was working correctly on the development server).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the lookup logic for `@member` and `@organization` both rely on having `params[:email]` set:

```
@member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
@organization = Organization.find_by(email: params[:email])
```

But you are passing in a blank `email`:

```
get edit_password_reset_path(member.reset_token, email: "")
```

You need to pass in a valid email for an Organization and Member that exists in your test database.  You may need to create the records during test setup using fixtures, factories or plain old ActiveRecord create.